# AS3 remove MC from dynamic path reference with removeChild

Tags: actionscript-3, path, reference, movieclip, removechild

I'm not even sure if the title reflects what I want to do. Here's backstory. I have a movieclip with 5 'holder' movieclips in them. They are my containers for dynamically added movieclips.

The parent containers has an instance name of pyramid, the holder instance names are labeled after the 6 food groups, i.e., 'grainholder', 'fruitholder', 'vegetableholder', etc etc...

The holders are within the pyramid container, instance names as above, and the pyramid container is added to the display list. I have a addFoodToPyramid() function which adds 'foodMC' mc's to their respective holders. So an [object Apple] will be dynamically added by way of pyramid.fruitholder.addChild(Apple). The function also adds a listener. Heres the call and the function:

The call (I will use grains as example) is this:

```
addFoodToPyramid(grainArray, grainHolder, grainCounter);
```

And the function is:

function addFoodToPyramid(thisArray:Array, thisHolder:MovieClip, thisCounter:Number):void
      {

```
   thisCounter = 0;

   for (var f:Number=0; f<thisArray.length; f++)
   {

    trace(thisArray.length);
    foodMC = (thisArray[f] as MovieClip);
    trace(foodMC);
    thisHolder.addChild(foodMC);
    foodMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startFoodDrag, false, 0, true);
    thisMC.scaleX = thisMC.scaleY = .7;
    thisMC.x = 60 * thisCounter;
    thisCounter++;

   }

  }
```

Then I have a startDrag function:

```
function startFoodDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
```

{
   foodDrag = e.target as MovieClip;
   foodDrag.startDrag();
   foodPoint = new Point(foodDrag.x,foodDrag.y);
   stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopFoodDrag, false, 0, true);
  }

Then the drop function AND THE PROBLEM LIES HERE:

```
foodDrag = foodDrop;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopFoodDrag);
if(foodDrag.dropTarget.parent==myPlate){
```

//HERES THE PROBLEM
      removeChild(foodDrag);  //obviously returns error because the foodDrag reference is wrong

}

Ok, so obviously the reference is not a direct removeChild() but a specific path. Like:

```
pyramid.*THE-HOLDER-OF-foodDRAG*.removeChild(foodDrag).
```

But I just can't get my head around how to do it. I've tried:

```
var mcParent:MovieClip=(foodDroppedMC.parent);
pyramid.mcParent.removeChild(foodDroppedMC);
```

// returns error 1118 Implicit Coercion

I've tried:

```
var mcParent:String=(foodDroppedMC.parent.name);
pyramid.getChildByName(mcParent).removeChild(foodDroppedMC);
```

// return 1061 Call to possibly undefined method removeChild with ref to static type etc etc

The fact that it's such a banal problem is what makes it so frustrating...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of trouble following the details of your question (I think maybe some of the "drop function" got lost in your post somehow).

But if the question is:  how do I remove a movie clip from its parent, without knowing an exact path to the parent?  then the answer is simply:

```
foodDrag.parent.removeChild(foodDrag);
```

assuming that `foodDrag` is your movie clip that you want to remove.

If I'm missing the point, please reply and help me understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this AND IT WORKS!!!:

```
var mcParent:String=(foodDroppedMC.parent.name);
pyramid[mcParent].removeChild(foodDroppedMC);
```

If anyone can give some insight as to how this works I'd love to know. I assume the mcParent with type of "String" is make the (foodDroppedMC.parent.name) a string and the the [] brackets in the mc path are somehow casting it as a MC so there is no Implicit Coercion. That's my guess... lol.

Anyway, happy days. Feel free to expand on this solution. I'm not really sure Google University (where I got my Flash as3 degree =P) teaches much about the []'s being used other than with Arrays.

Comment: the `[]` operator applied to an object, treats that object as an associative hash.  It allows you to access properties of that object using a string containing the name of the property.  [Check adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eea.html) for a thorough explanation of associative hashes.  (incidentally, the link above is part of a much larger document that you may find very helpful).

Comment: I should also point out that, if you just want to remove `foodDroppedMC`, all you have to do is `foodDropMC.parent.removeChild(foodDroppedMC)`.  That's all.  You don't need to resolve the parent through the `pyramid` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You're right - I should have just written it foodDropMC.parent.removeChild(foodDroppedMC). *Smacks head* The lesson to be learned here is make something complex but never any more than it should be.